# The manuscript status suddenly changed to “Draft Status” in ScholarOne

Tags: publications, journals, journal-workflow

About two weeks ago, we submitted a paper to a Taylor & Francis journal that uses the ScholarOne manuscript-submission system. We also received an e-mail confirming that the submission process is complete and that the editor is considering the paper for publication.

Today, I checked the status and it has now changed to ***Draft Status***. I have never seen something like this in my previous submissions. I would be very grateful if someone could possibly tell me if I need to contact the editor or do something specific.

Comment: Have you contacted the editor to ask about the change in status?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually, no. I am not the corresponding author and therefore thought it would be inappropriate to contact the editor to ask about the current status. Do you think I should?

Comment: I guess, the manuscript has been "unsubmitted" because of some reason. Contact the editorial chief or Journal manager.

Answer (score 4):

We were recently informed that the manuscript exceeded the word count set by the journal and therefore was unsubmitted. We were asked to revise and re-submit the paper.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reason stated in the answer by @Mehrdad:

I had submitted my manuscript (in PDF) to one journal in Wiley using ScholarOne (ManuscriptCentral) on July 8.

Today, on July 10, I received the email from the editorial office saying the same thing and status being changed to "Draft".

**Reason:** In the submission site, it was asked to submit a single PDF during INITIAL SUBMISSION (Latex file is not required). But, still, they needed the editable source file to be uploaded as "Supplementary File for Review".

Answer (score 0):

This's a common status for Taylor and Francis publisher. Your manuscript requires some changes in its body style before sending for the peer-reviewing process. Recheck your style and bibliography format to finalize your submission.